# How do I add a hyperlink to an image located inside a data array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to an image that is located inside a data array and cannot figure it out. I want the link to point to `JackRussell.html`. Maybe someone here can help me out. The code is inside the `index.js` page.

```
data = [
   {
      "animal":"Dog",
      "type":"Jack Russell Terrier",
      "image":"img/JackRussell.jpg"
   }

];
```

I've tried the following code and the picture shows up but no hyper link were created as a result

"image":"img/JackRussell.jpg.http://www.jackrussell.html

What I need as a final result is to make the image clickable and take to me the corresponding page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How to render the list?

Comment: can you share your html? how is this data being used?

Comment: It may help to see the rest of the relevant HTML and JS. For something to be a link, it either has to be inside an `<a>` tag with the `href` value set to your address, like so: `<a href="http://www.google.com">The blue hyperlink text</a>`, or be given an `onClick` behavior via JS. In your case, I'd imagine the `<img>` could most likely be placed inside an `<a>` tag wherever your HTML references the value stored in the object (or where your JS references the HTML element).

Comment: I know that creating a regular hyperlink I can use the "<a href="#"></a>" but I when I tried using this format inside the data = [
    {
      animal: "Dog",
     "type: "Jack Russell Terrier",
      "image": "img/JackRussell.jpg",
    
    }
  ];  everything breaks down.

Comment: Hi Dan, here is the URL for the code I'm using. https://codepen.io/ericwinton/pen/jqKyyq

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple as long as you have the name of the page you want to go to:

```js
const data = [{
  animal: "Dog",
  type: "Jack Russell Terrier",
  image: "img/JackRussel.jpg",
  page: "jackrussell.html"
}];
let myDog = data[0];
document.getElementById("linkBox").innerHTML = `<a href="${myDog.page}"><img src="${myDog.image}" alt="This is a(n) ${myDog.type}" title="${myDog.animal}"></a>`;
```

```html
<div id="linkBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [W3school | HTML Images](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) the below is simple example to open the link in new tab using `target="blank"`

```
<a href="car.jpeg" target="blank">
<img src="car.jpeg"></img>
</a>
```

In your example if the clickable link is the image URL, check the below

```js
data = [
 {
  "make": "Gibson",
  "model": "Les Paul",
  "type": "Electric",
  "price": "$3,000",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/LPST5HTHDCH-medium.jpg?9782bd"
 },
 {
  "make": "Gibson",
  "model": "SG",
  "type": "Electric",
  "price": "$1,500",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/SGSEBCH-medium.jpg?e69cfe"
 },
 {
  "make": "Fender",
  "model": "Telecaster",
  "type": "Electric",
  "price": "$2,000",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/TelePLMPHB-medium.jpg?28e48b"
 },
 {
  "make": "Fender",
  "model": "Stratocaster",
  "type": "Electric",
  "price": "$2,000",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/StratAMM3SB2-medium.jpg?dfd0a9"
 },
 {
  "make": "Gretsch",
  "model": "White Falcon",
  "type": "Electric",
  "price": "$5,000",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/G613655GE-medium.jpg?9bfb0e"
 },
 {
  "make": "Paul Reed Smith",
  "model": "Custom 24",
  "type": "Electric",
  "price": "$5,000",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/HBII10BGWB-medium.jpg?982763"
 },
 {
  "make": "Gibson",
  "model": "Hummingbird",
  "type": "Acoustic",
  "price": "$2,500",
  "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/SSHBHCNP-medium.jpg?11fbea"
 }
];

var products = "",
 makes = "",
 models = "",
 types = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 var make = data[i].make,
  model = data[i].model,
  type = data[i].type,
  price = data[i].price,
  rawPrice = price.replace("$",""),
  rawPrice = parseInt(rawPrice.replace(",","")),
  image = data[i].image;
 
 //create product cards
 products += "<div class='col-sm-4 product' data-make='" + make + "' data-model='" + model + "' data-type='" + type + "' data-price='" + rawPrice + "'><div class='product-inner text-center'><a href='"+ image +"' target='blank'><img src='" + image + "'></a><br />Make: " + make + "<br />Model: " + model + "<br />Type: " + type + "<br />Price: " + price + "</div></div>";
 
 //create dropdown of makes
 if (makes.indexOf("<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + "</option>") == -1) {
  makes += "<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + "</option>";
 }
 
 //create dropdown of models
 if (models.indexOf("<option value='" + model+"'>" + model + "</option>") == -1) {
  models += "<option value='" + model + "'>" + model + "</option>";
 }
 
 //create dropdown of types
 if (types.indexOf("<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + "</option>") == -1) {
  types += "<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + "</option>";
 }
}

$("#products").html(products);
$(".filter-make").append(makes);
$(".filter-model").append(models);
$(".filter-type").append(types);

var filtersObject = {};

//on filter change
$(".filter").on("change",function() {
 var filterName = $(this).data("filter"),
  filterVal = $(this).val();
 
 if (filterVal == "") {
  delete filtersObject[filterName];
 } else {
  filtersObject[filterName] = filterVal;
 }
 
 var filters = "";
 
 for (var key in filtersObject) {
    if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   filters += "[data-"+key+"='"+filtersObject[key]+"']";
   }
 }
 
 if (filters == "") {
  $(".product").show();
 } else {
  $(".product").hide();
  $(".product").hide().filter(filters).show();
 }
});

//on search form submit
$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var query = $("#search-form input").val().toLowerCase();

 $(".product").hide();
 $(".product").each(function() {
  var make = $(this).data("make").toLowerCase(),
   model = $(this).data("model").toLowerCase(),
   type = $(this).data("type").toLowerCase();

  if (make.indexOf(query) > -1 || model.indexOf(query) > -1 || type.indexOf(query) > -1) {
   $(this).show();
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 padding-top: 30px;
}
.product {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.product-inner {
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 padding: 10px;
}
.product img {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" id="search">
  <form id="search-form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="filter">
  <form>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="make" class="filter-make filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Make</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="model" class="filter-model filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Model</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="type" class="filter-type filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Type</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="price" class="filter-price filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Price Range</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="products">
  
 </div>
</div>
```